# Wrong Limit[...] for inexact expressions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, machine-precision

I noticed that `Limit` can return nonsense when using inexact parameters. In the following code, `a` is my (exact/inexact) parameter, and I want to know the limit for `b -> 1` (or `b -> 1.`, this does not matter).

```
expr := Limit[(-b*Cos[a*b] Sin[a/2] + Sin[a*b] Cos[a/2])/(b^2 - 1), b -> 1];
a = 2. Pi;
expr    (* Returns -Infinity *)
a = 2 Pi;
expr    (* Returns -Pi *)
```

I observe this behavior in Mathematica 8, 9, and 10.

I then turned to the documentation of `Limit`, which states:

> Limit may return an incorrect answer for an inexact input:
>
> ```
> Limit[Log[1 - (Log[Exp[z]/z - 1] + Log[z])/z]/z, z -> 100.] 
> (* -Infinity *)
> ```
>
> The result is correct when an exact input is used:
>
> ```
> Limit[Log[1 - (Log[Exp[z]/z - 1] + Log[z])/z]/z, z -> 100]
> (* 1/100 Log[1 - 1/100 Log[-100 + E^100]] *)
> ```

I can see why `Limit` fails here: The subexpression `1 - 1/100*Log[-100 + E^100]` evaluates to approximately 4*10^-44, which is prohibitively small (in single precision, but not in double - this confuses me a bit).

In my example, however, I can't see tiny or huge numbers that could cause this sort of problem. Can you help me see my error?

Edit: I found this problem when I was calculating the Fourier transform of an RF-pulse to find the maximum power density of its spectrum.

Comment: `Trace[expr]` should help to clarify why the approximate case gives what it gives.

Comment: Have a look at a = 2. \[Pi] and a = 2 Pi without the semicolon 2 Pi ist not the same as 2*Pi, see also [Trace](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) as stated by @Daniel Lichtblau

Comment: @Louis: I am thoroughly confused. What do the square brackets in `a = 2. [Pi]` mean? I see that the output is different, but I am unfamiliar with that syntax (and could not find it [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/14168) or [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)). Further, I don't see different output when not using the semicolon, or why `2 Pi` is not equal to `2*Pi`.

Comment: 2. Pi  leads to 6.28319 and 2 Pi leads to 2 \[Pi], and try the Trace thing

Comment: I think @Louis is saying that "2*Pi" and "2.*Pi" are different, but you already knew that. Try setting `a` to `2*Pi+e` to see an odd result: apparently, there's a sign change in the limit near 2*Pi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica knows how to simplify when `a` is exactly `2*Pi`:

```
(-b*Cos[a*b] Sin[a/2] + Sin[a*b] Cos[a/2])/(b^2 - 1) /. a -> 2*Pi // InputForm 
-(Sin[2*b*Pi]/(-1 + b^2))
```

It then applies the numerical limit for b=1.

For the approximate number `2.*Pi`, Mathematica can't make this 
simplification, and it turns out the limit is +Infinity for `a<2*Pi` 
and -Infinity for `a>2*Pi`, so even a small variation from `2*Pi` 
completely changes the problem:

```
 
expr := Limit[(-b*Cos[a*b] Sin[a/2] + Sin[a*b] Cos[a/2])/(b^2 - 1), b -> 1]; 
a = 2*Pi-10^-10 
expr (* yields Infinity *) 
a = 2*Pi+10^-10 
expr (* yields -Infinity *) 
a = 2*Pi 
expr (* yields -Pi as expected *)
```

And if we let `e` represent an arbitrary distance from 2*Pi:

```
a = 2*Pi + e 
expr // InputForm 
(* yields DirectedInfinity[(I*Sign[-1 + E^(I*e)])/E^((I/2)*Re[e])] *)
```

So why does `2.*Pi` return -Infinity? Because it's actually a little 
different from `2*Pi`:

```
 
a = 2.*Pi; 
SetPrecision[a, Infinity] (* result: 884279719003555/140737488355328 *) 
expr (* -Infinity *)
```

Comment: Barry, maybe I am misunderstanding, but the expression has a removable discontinuity at $b=1$. The limits approaching from either side of $1$ are the same, and equal to $\pi$, *not* infinity. You can convince yourself of this by plotting this expression in the neighbourhood of $b=1$ after substituting the $a=2\pi$ value in it ([plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AreCl.png)).

Comment: I meant setting `a` equal to `2*Pi-e` and `2*Pi+e` and then taking the limit. If Mathematica is accurate above, a small change in `a` makes the limit infinite.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying; I see your point now.